# QLayout and Valgrind

Tags: qt, c++17, valgrind, qlayout

I've been struggling with a message from Valgrind.
I'm using a QLayout taken from Qt examples (FlowLayout) and I add at runtime, when the user presses an add button, some widgets to this layout.
This is the initialitation snippet inside a constructor of my container QWidget class inherited:

```
// scroll area
auto* central = new QWidget();
central->setObjectName("CentralWidget");
m_layout = new FlowLayout;
ui->scrollArea_step->setFrameShape(QFrame::NoFrame);
central->setLayout(m_layout);
ui->scrollArea_step->setWidgetResizable(true);
ui->scrollArea_step->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
ui->scrollArea_step->setWidget(central);
```

I've understood that because of the setWidget(central), I don't need to assign a parent to the "central" widget.

When the user clicks the add button into the interface, the program invokes this snippet:

```
// create the button from rf data
ShortMenuPushButton* stepButton = _createStepButton(m_rfData);
m_layout->addWidget(stepButton);
QPushButton* deleteStepButton = _createDeleteButton();
m_layout->addWidget(deleteStepButton);
```

_createStepButton has this code:

```
auto* stepButton = new ShortMenuPushButton(this);
```

The same operation is done by _createDeleteButton() for the other button.

If I run Valgrind, I get the same message:

```
==59123== 176 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 8,040 of 8,630
==59123==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==59123==    by 0x6430849: QLayoutPrivate::createWidgetItem(QLayout const*, QWidget*) (qlayout.cpp:200)
==59123==    by 0x6431AA0: QLayout::addWidget(QWidget*) (qlayout.cpp:236)
==59123==    by 0x7DA967: Dialogs::Dialog_multistep::onButtonAddStep_clicked() (dialog_multistep.cpp:419)
==59123==    by 0x7E8B13: QtPrivate::FunctorCall<QtPrivate::IndexesList<>, QtPrivate::List<>, void, void (Dialogs::Dialog_multistep::*)()>::call(void (Dialogs::Dialog_multistep::*)(), Dialogs::Dialog_multistep*, void**) (qobjectdefs_impl.h:152)
==59123==    by 0x7E8A87: void QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<void (Dialogs::Dialog_multistep::*)()>::call<QtPrivate::List<>, void>(void (Dialogs::Dialog_multistep::*)(), Dialogs::Dialog_multistep*, void**) (qobjectdefs_impl.h:185)
==59123==    by 0x7E89B4: QtPrivate::QSlotObject<void (Dialogs::Dialog_multistep::*)(), QtPrivate::List<>, void>::impl(int, QtPrivate::QSlotObjectBase*, QObject*, void**, bool*) (qobjectdefs_impl.h:414)
==59123==    by 0x9284CB5: call (qobjectdefs_impl.h:394)
==59123==    by 0x9284CB5: QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) (qobject.cpp:3774)
==59123==    by 0x64FAFF1: QAbstractButton::clicked(bool) (moc_qabstractbutton.cpp:312)
==59123==    by 0x64FB1F3: QAbstractButtonPrivate::emitClicked() (qabstractbutton.cpp:414)
==59123==    by 0x64FCD8D: QAbstractButtonPrivate::click() (qabstractbutton.cpp:407)
==59123==    by 0x64FCEE4: QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) (qabstractbutton.cpp:1011)
```

But in FlowLayout I've the distructor with:

```
void FlowLayout::clear()
{
    QLayoutItem* item;
    while ((item = takeAt(0)))
    {
        delete item->widget();
    }
}
```

I do not understand where the leak is.

I appreciate any suggestion.
Thank you

Comment: The leak is only there if you can make it grow. Try and increase the size of the leak 10-100 times. If you can’t, there’s no real leak. :)

Comment: Of course, I've done in this way. I've added several items. This is the result.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem.
As I wrote, I've used the class FlowLayout, taken from a famous example (Qt).
The method clear does:

```
void FlowLayout::clear()
{
    QLayoutItem* item;
    while ((item = takeAt(0)))
    {
        delete item->widget();
    }
}
```

but the QLayoutItem return *nullptr* in the method *QLayoutItem::widget()*.

Maybe because QLayoutItem is a base class and should be derived.